# Selection algorithm from an array of square with radius?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, select

As is an algorithm which selects the elements of the array at a predetermined radius from the support element?

For example I select item 28 (see the picture), radius = 1 selected :

```
19 20 21 
27 28 29
35 36 37
```

if support element is 1 radius = 1 selected:

```
1 2
9 10
```

The algorithm is to take 28 item check whether the elements above to take it (20), check whether there is a higher take it (12), followed by 20 and 12 check and take the right elements within a radius of 2, rotated 90 degrees and repeat.

That for the algorithm or what it looks like ?

Visualization of the algorithm:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy0Uu.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your selected element is at `(row, col)`, it looks like a simple matter of traversing the submatrix with `(row, col)` at its center.

We must take care to avoid out of bounds issues.

Pseudocode:

```
for rowIndex = max(0, row - radius) to min(matrixHeight - 1, row + radius)
  for colIndex = max(0, col - radius) to min(matrixWidth - 1, col + radius)
    take element at (rowIndex, colIndex)
```

If you also want to color the elements like in your image, then this is easily done by comparing the position `(rowIndex, colIndex)` with that of `(row, col)`: for example, if `rowIndex >  row` and `colIndex >= colIndex`, then color that element `red`.